# How can I plot a square and colour map it using a 2d array of values

Tags: python, matplotlib, graph

For example I have 2 arrays that are x, y co-ordinates and a square grid that corresponds to each point.

```
x = np.linspace(0,10,50)
y = np.linspace(-5,12,50)
square = np.empty((50,50))
```

I'm trying to plot out a square surface that is cmaped by the square values. I did get it to work with surface plotting but the issue is the surface has an irregular shape and I can't plot some scatter points over it, without visibility issues.

I'm wondering if there's a way to get it to work as a 2d plot rather than 3d as the Z cordinate can just be replaced by a cmap and make sense. Any suggestions?

Comment: https://matplotlib.org/stable/plot_types/index#plots-of-arrays-and-fields

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because this info would have been available with a cursory look at Matplotlib documentation, and hence is not of general interest

Answer (score 0):

So I did find a solution:

```
x_mesh, y_mesh = np.meshgrid(x,y)

fig = plt.figure(dpi = 200)
plt.scatter(x_mesh,y_mesh, c = square, cmap = 'viridis')
plt.show
```

With enough points it gets a good surface.